# Математические вычисления в pwsh

Tags: математика, powershell, матрицы

Интересует наличие матриц в PowerShell Core. Они есть или нужно реализовать свой класс через Add-Type? Или все же есть какие-то альтернативы?

Answer (score 1):

Тип `Matrix` есть в сборке `WindowsBase`, однако в шестой версии `PowerShell` последняя является заглушкой, в седьмой версии - все на своих местах. Пример ниже показывает как можно вычислить тысячный элемент последовательности Фибоначчи методом матриц.

```
#requires -version 7
using namespace System.Windows.Media

Add-Type -AssemblyName WindowsBase

$m1, $m2 = [Matrix]::new(1,0,0,1,0,0), [Matrix]::new(1,1,1,0,0,0)
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 1000; $i++) { $m1 *= $m2 }
$m1.M11
```

Опираясь на личный опыт могу сказать, что для научных вычислений `PowerShell` применять можно, но делать этого все же не стоит. Лучше использовать `Julia` - вот там действительно с математикой все без заморочек, да и скорость вычислений достаточно неплохая.